# Is it possibl to send sslv2 hello messages from a client using java socket

Tags: java, ssl, network-programming

Is it possible to send sslv2 hello messages?? When I try initiating ssl handshake with a remote server, the default version is `TLS`. I need to test if the serve accepts sslv2, therefore, I need to force my Java program to send sslv2 hello message. Is this possible? How? Please note that I need to this for testing only. I am not doing a real Java application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initiate ssl connection using SSLv2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773692/how-to-initiate-ssl-connection-using-sslv2)

Answer (score 2):

Sun/Oracle Java has never supported SSLv2. It did support the SSLv2ClientHello *message*, for compatibility purposes, to negotiate SSLv3 or higher, but that was withdrawn in I think 1.7. IBM Java used to support SSLv2 but I can't speak for current versions.

Answer (score 1):

SSLV2 is not supported, if you need to force `SSLv2Hello` messages you can set a system property :

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3,SSLv2Hello");
```

Or you can manage your sockets directly :

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sock = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket("hostserver", 443);
String[] protocols = {"SSLv2Hello", "SSLv3", "TLSv1"};
```