# Effects of Enabling TLS1.2 in weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, tls1.2

I have a weblogic 10.3.6 installed in windows server 2008 R2 64-bit with Java 7 update 111. With in weblogic server I have 4 manged server running many java applications.

I have new client web-services application need to be deployed in one of the 4 manged server and this application require TLS1.2 as requested by third party services provider application. For that purpose, I am setting the following property in client application code like `System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");`

**Question:**

Will the statement `System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");` change the protocol for only manged server where the application is deployed ? Or it will be for all application servers available  within weblogic ?

If this command change the protocol for all manged servers, then this is a problem since other applications may get affected. What is the solution in this case and what is the right action to be taken to enable the required SSL protocol for that specific application without affecting other running applications ?

Answer (score 0):

- It should affect all managed servers on that box (probably after the nodes are restarted)
- TLS is compatible with SSL - just not with insecure handshake protocols (which you should have stopped doing years ago) For more information, see: [Modifiying Weblogic Server to use TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016744/modifiying-weblogic-server-to-use-tls)